# CASE Function in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I can't get the result I want from the following query. Can I get a little help, please? thank you.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, 
                 CASE 
                    when Rcon = '' then '0',
                    when Rcon = 'x' then '1',
                    when Rcon = '2x' then '2',
                    when Rcon = 'x3' then '2',
                    when Rcon = 'x,x3' then '3',
                    when Rcon = 'x4' then '3' 
                    ELSE Rcon END AS Rcon
FROM mytable";
```

Comment: what do you want to do in else part?

Comment: In else part, I tried to give an option if there is any unexpected data.

Comment: if you just read the error message raised from mysql you can get what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem with your `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT  id, 
        CASE 
          when Rcon = '' then '0'
          when Rcon = 'x' then '1'
          when Rcon = '2x' then '2'
          when Rcon = 'x3' then '2'
          when Rcon = 'x,x3' then '3'
          when Rcon = 'x4' then '3' 
          ELSE Rcon 
        END AS Rcon
  FROM mytable;
```

Note that I have removed the commas (`,`) from the end of each line of the `CASE` statement.  Commas are not valid in a case statement.

Comment: so just the comma does the trick? thank you, Martin. this works!

Comment: @Max Yes it's just the commas - you don't need them in a `CASE` statment